# Python/Pandas: How to detect if trend is suddenly increasing "X" amount

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to detect if I have some certain log event that is increasing "X" amount of percent, and then get the top 10 increased trends.

I would have thought that pct_change().mean() would give me what I needed, but it seems I am getting some weird results.

So this is what I got

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sample = "sampledata.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(sample, sep=";")

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],
                              format='%d-%m-%Y')

grp = df.groupby(['DATE','EVENT'])['COUNT'].sum()


grp
DATE        EVENT 
2020-05-01  DOE711      2
            ODO001     32
2020-05-02  ODO001      3
2020-05-03  DOE711      1
2020-05-04  DOE711     62
            ODO001     46
2020-05-05  DOE711    101
            ODO001     43
2020-05-06  DOE711     65
            ODO001     61
2020-05-07  DOE711    102
            ODO001     26
2020-05-08  ODO001     16
2020-05-09  ODO001      3
2020-05-10  ODO001      5
Name: COUNT, dtype: int64

grp.groupby('EVENT').apply(lambda x: x.pct_change().mean()).reset_index(name='avg_change').nlargest(10,'avg_change')

EVENT   avg_change
0   DOE711  12.268365
1   ODO001  1.584531

grp = grp.reset_index()
grp = grp.set_index('DATE')

grp[grp.EVENT == "ODO001"].COUNT.plot()
```

[image]

Now, ODO001 is 1.58. which should indicate that the trend is increasing, BUT:
If I import the data to excel, and ask excel to create a linear trend line,
it says it's decreasing

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to solve this?

After the answer from: @Marco Cerliani
 this is the result.

So this should be translatable to this:

```
def trend(series):
    return np.polyfit(np.arange(0,len(series)), series.values, 1)[0]

trend(grp[grep.EVENT == "ODO001"].COUNT)
```

or in groupby

```
df.groupby('EVENT').apply(lambda x: trend(x.count))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mean pct change and the linear trend have different behavior. look at my simulate example:

```
start = 100
end = 0
peak = 1000
steps = 50

series = pd.Series(np.append(start, np.arange(end, peak+steps, steps)[::-1]))
series.plot()
```

[image]

this series has a pct mean change of 0.257 (`series.pct_change().mean()`) and negative linear coefficient -38.73 (`np.polyfit(np.arange(0,len(series)), series.values, 1)[0]`)

We have a single huge positive pct increase while all the other pct changes are negative, but this is sufficient to have a mean positive (this is classical for mean index when there are extreme outliers). The trend instead is more significative for the linear pattern in the data

I suggest you use directly the linear coefficient. you can simply compute it with `np.polyfit`

Comment: ahh, did'nt realize code blocks was not supported,
added my results in my post, thanks for the help, could you confirm if my results above is correct?

Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, something similar... before check if it works outside groupby and then try to incorporate into it... don't forget to upvote or accept it as answer ;-)